# using jetty on android to server static file

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I created the class WebProvider to add a jetty server to my android app and to server static resources.
I start the server with a button but I can't access the address http://localhost:8080.

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler;

public class WebProvider {
    private static Server server;
    private static HandlerCollection hc;
    private static String path;



    public void startServer(){
        if(this.path != null && !this.path.isEmpty()){
            this.server = new Server(8080);

            this.hc = new HandlerCollection(true);

            this.setResources(this.path);

            this.server.setHandler(this.hc);

            try {
                this.server.start();
                this.server.join();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public void setResources(String path){
        if(this.hc!= null){
            this.path = path;
            Handler[] allHandler = this.hc.getHandlers();
            if(allHandler != null){
                for(int i=0;i<allHandler.length;i++){
                    this.hc.removeHandler(allHandler[i]);
                }
            }
            ResourceHandler resourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();
            resourceHandler.setResourceBase(path);
            this.hc.addHandler(resourceHandler);
        }else{
            this.path = path;
        }
    }
}
```

I call the server to set the resources in the callback of one button and then I start the server in the callback of the other button.

Button 1

```
WebProvider si = new WebProvider();
si.setResources(this.url);
```

Button 2

```
WebProvider si = new WebProvider();
si.startServer();
```

Comment: What version of Jetty?

Comment: I used jetty Version 8.2

Comment: Might want to at least downgrade to Jetty version `8.1.22.v20160922` (as 8.2+ is for Java 8+).  it will make your life a bit easier on Android by avoiding the fight against Java 8 specific code.

Comment: Also, the last confirmed version of Jetty to support Android (as part of the [i-jetty project](https://github.com/jetty-project/i-jetty)) was Jetty 7.6.0.RC4

Comment: Thanks I’ll try that :)